# Developing spring action in corona

Tags: coronasdk

I am trying to develop a spring which has its one end attached to a static roof and the other end has a body with mass m attached to it.

Whenever I drag the load(body attached to spring) the spring must also get displaced from its mean position and must behave like a real spring, after few oscillations it must come back to initial position.

Now I have developed a spring using a few rectangles which are joined using a pivot joint, a load is also attached using the pivot joint. Here when I drag the load, the spring oscillates from left to right like a pendulum and not like a real spring. I want oscillation up and down and not left to right.

Comment: Please post what you have so far

Comment: Am I just missing it? I don't see any code

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ludicroussoftware.com/blog/2011/09/01/corona-physics-forced-bouncing/

Comment: This link is not working anymore