# Elasticity behaviour for a rope in 2d game

Tags: sdk, 2d, coronasdk

I am developing a game in which I want to have an elastic rope. I am developing using the Corona SDK. Anyone who is developing game other than Corona can also help if they have come across such situation.

I would like it to be similar to [what is shown in this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zpwuOcKIorI&feature=g-hist&context=G2eb8686AHT1sXVQABAA).

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with mobile development, but what you're after is a physics library, one that implements Hooke's Law. Googling these terms gave me some other stackoverflow results:

[Developing spring action in corona](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162103/developing-spring-action-in-corona)

Answer (score 0):

I dont't know about corona, but the global idea is to render an **arc** that have a **default radius = 0** and when user execute the event you want the radius will be **increased gradually** and **decreased gradually** after some moment